# Play Framework jsRoutes Showing 500 error on POST

Tags: jquery, angularjs, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to post data from an AngularJS interface through my JavaScript routes back to my Application.java controller.

I've created my javascriptRoutes() in app/controllers/Application.java:

```
public static Result javascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
            controllers.routes.javascript.Application.duplicateSheet()
        )
    );
}
```

I've set up my route so that it comes before the assets/public route:

```
POST  /sheet/duplicate/    controllers.Application.duplicateSheet()
GET   /assets/javascripts/routes    controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

And in my JS controller I'm attempting to call my duplicateSheet() function:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.duplicateSheet().ajax({
        data: {
            newSheet: newSheet,
                includeData: includeData
        }
});
```

When I try to run the duplicateSheet() I get the following error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:9000/sheet/duplicate/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is this is telling me that my jsRoutes work, but that the '/sheet/duplicate/' route doesn't exist? Is there something else I'm missing about the routes?

Comment: AFAIK, it means that your `duplicateSheet` action is run, but contains an error. Anything in the log files or in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

After checking the Play logs/application.log - which the same output can also be seen in the terminal window that is running the Play application process - I discovered that the JSON string I was posting to the duplicateSheet() was malformed and causing Java errors.

After addressing the issues found in the logs I was able to get the application to post properly.